# Python Speech-to-Text translation for Speaker voice

Tags: python-3.x, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I'm worried that is there any way to do speech to text translation for speaker voice.

**Scenario:**

Doing runtime translation of voice(speech) to text when I'm in call through **Teams** or **Skype** for both sides of user in call.

I tried with Google Api as well as Microsoft Api, but in both, it's only doing translation for one side voice not for other side voice in call. I tried with `Microphone()` function from `speech_recognition` python package, but, no luck.

I searched everywhere in Internet, but all are giving example of speech recognition(speech-to-text translation) through Microphone and with recorded audio file(.wav). Through recorded file, I'm able to achieve this, but, I want to do in real time translation when I'm in call through **Teams** or **Skype**.

If anyone have any knowledge in this, please share.
Thanks in Advance.

**Note:** I can re-explain this, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import speech_recognition as sr

for index, name in enumerate(sr.Microphone.list_microphone_names()):
    print("Microphone with name \"{1}\" found for `Microphone(device_index {0})`".format(index, name))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please explain how this piece of code works and how it  helps solve the problem in question.